# searching a text file the writing result to memo, lazarus

Tags: lazarus, text-files

this segment in my program first ads a customer to a textfile (declared in public variables) and saves it to a texfile. onbutton1click is the procudere to search the string thats in the editbox and return the relevant customer details to memo. the add customer works fine and adds to textfile, however when i search it returns nothing onto the memo, just the memo caption, memo1. any way i can resolve this? sorry im a newb to this.

```
  procedure TForm2.btnsaveClick(Sender: TObject);

  begin
     cusfname:= edit1.text ;
     cuslname:= edit2.text;
     adress:= edit3.text;
     phone:= edit4.text;
     password:= edit5.Text;
     AssignFile(F, 'Data.txt');
     append(F);
     WriteLn(F, cusfname);
     WriteLn(F, cuslname);
     WriteLn(F, adress);
     WriteLn(F, phone);
     WriteLn(F, password);
     CloseFile(F);
    end;

   procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

   var

     SearchFile : Textfile;
     found: boolean;
     search: string;

    begin
    search := edit1.text;
    Assignfile(SearchFile, 'data.txt');
    Reset(SearchFile);
    found:= false;
    repeat
      found:= search = phone
    until eof(searchfile) or found;
    if found then
    memo1.append(phone);
    memo1.append(cusfname);
    memo1.append(adress);
    if not found then 
      showmessage('member not found');
   end;
```

Answer (score 0):

wonder where are the read statements?  In the write function you have Write() statements, but in the reading code no read() statements?

Comment: begin
reset(searchfile);
  Assignfile(SearchFile, 'data.txt');
  Reset(SearchFile);
  found:= false;
  search := edit1.text ;
  repeat
  read(searchfile, phone) ;
  read(searchfile, cusfname);
  read(searchfile, adress);
  found:= search = phone
  until eof(searchfile) or found;
  if found then
  memo1.append(phone);
  memo1.append(cusfname);
  memo1.append(adress);
  closefile(searchfile) ;
  if not found then showmessage('member not found');

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do not `read()` from file. In other similar question (probably your own): [runerror(102) file not assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013629/runerror102-file-not-assigned) there is `read()`. But I think you should use `readln()`, or even better use [`TStringList`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList) class from `Classes` unit with its `LoadFromFile()` method and `Lines` property.